# oracle select & update or select & insert in multithreaded env

Tags: sql, multithreading, oracle, plsql

I have a problem and I have the impression that the solution is simple but I cannot figure it out.

A have a multi threaded env and a pl sql stored procedure.
Inside this procedure I have something like that :

```
select * into mycount from toto;
If mycount >0 then update...;
else insert ...;
```

The problem is that I have many threads calling this procedure.
Is there a simple way to have only one thread at a time executing the piece of code above ?
I know that I can use `select for update` but since I could have an UPDATE or INSERT I guess this does not works for me.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Try To add a commit at the end of the procedure call, so the thread by end will not maitain exclusive DML operations on your tables. Any DDL may break the Lock.

Comment: The first `select` isn't necessary. Just run the `update` and check the number of rows updated. It that is zero, do the insert (that way the "select" will only be done once). Or use the `MERGE` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a separate table MODIFY_CHECKER with just one column FLAG. Use this table & column as a means to allow only one thread to update/insert on your actual table (TOTO I suppose)

You could add something like the below to your existing PL/SQL procedure -

```
IF (select count(1) from modify_checker where flag = 1) > 0 THEN
  -- Another thread is already working, so just raise exception
  RAISE <<exception>>
ELSE
  -- No other thread working on this, so go ahead
  UPDATE modify_checker SET flag = 1;
  COMMIT;
  <<actual code to update or insert actual table>>
  UPDATE modify_checker SET flag = 0;
  COMMIT;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for what you want would be to introduce an intermediary queue of some sort at the application level - the various threads would send a request to the queue and a queue processor would read requests off of the queue and make the necessary call to the DB.

This would, in my opinion, be the easiest solution in that you don't have to change too much to get it to work. The only potential problem is that this solution could be complicated if a response is necessary - if so this is still an option, but the app code is complicated a bit by having to deal with asynchronous responses.

Comment: Good idea but I cannont implement it because my stored procedure is called in different places and I cannot afford modifying every piece of code.

Comment: You will have to modify your code for any solution to work. You wont be able to do anything from the SQL server.

Comment: Another option is to have the current proc act as the "queue" and in turn call a new proc, perhaps using something like Oracle AQueues. Based on my experience with AQs though, this can be fiddly.  If you dont want to change the client code then I think that something along these lines might be your only option

Answer (score 0):

You can put a lock as soon as you access the procedure and the release it when you are exiting from it. This way only one can access this at a time.

ALTER TABLE tl_test ENABLE TABLE LOCK;

ALTER TABLE tl_test DISABLE TABLE LOCK;